# No application is open Robotframework using Appium on Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, appium, robotframework, appium-ios

i'm using robotframework & pycharm & appium. Appium works well but i tried to run robotframework on pycharm ,
there is no log on appium and it returns this error =>

Open My Application
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No application is open
| FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message:

Here is my code

First.robot

```
*** Settings ***


Library           AppiumLibrary



Suite Setup

*** Variables ***
${REMOTE_URL}           http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
${PLATFORM_NAME}        iOS
${PLATFORM_VERSION}     9.3
${DEVICE_NAME}          iPhone 6
${APP_LOCATION}         /Users/xxxx.yyy/ios-test-automation-with-gauge-new/ipa/GetX.app



*** Keywords ***
Open App
    Open Application    ${REMOTE_URL}   platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}   platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}    deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}   app=${APP_LOCATION}



Close All Apps
    Close All Applications
```

Second.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Resource          second.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Open My Application
Open App
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Well, if there is no log on Appium, it could mean that RobotFramework never connected to it. You have Appium server listening to `http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub` ?

Comment: Yes, In General Settings i've configured server 127.0.0.1 and port 4723 also i've run appium with intellij Idea, there is no problem

Comment: Try to avoid any manual step in Testing browser and then check there is any log or not.

Comment: There is no log on Appium Server about opening application.

Only it returns:

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 15 ms - 83

Comment: i solved this problem. Maybe others will be have this problem later. it's selenium version issue. i've last version 3.4.3 then i've downgraded selenium version 2.53.6 errors disappear.